# How to Display Items Count Inside each sub folder inside a document library SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, client-object-model

want to Display Items Count Inside each subfolder inside a document library SharePoint Online. using below code am getting all the folder items with count. using console application c#

```
            using (ClientContext ClientContext = new ClientContext(requestUrl))
        {
            List docList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestingFolder");
            clientContext.Load(docList); CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
            {
                if (listItem.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder Item :" + listItem.Id);

                }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
using (ClientContext ClientContext = new ClientContext(requestUrl))
{
    List docList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestingFolder");
    clientContext.Load(docList); CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
    {
        if (listItem.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
            context.Load(listItem, l => l.Folder);
            context.ExecuteQuery();         
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Item :" + listItem.Id + " Count:" + listItem.Folder.ItemCount);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```